# Deploy UWP package for enterprise without submitting to the store

Tags: xamarin, uwp

I would like to deploy a UWP package for enterprise. I have a Windows developer account but I don't want to publish it in Windows store or Enterprise store.
We have our URL to share the file, so the problem is when I try to install the Package in other PC the error 'Either you need a new certificate installed for this app package, or you need a new app package with trusted certificates' will occur.

Suggest the way to install it without publishing in store.

Comment: This is covered in the docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-distribute#distribute-your-application-without-placing-it-onto-the-microsoft-store

Answer (score 2):

For your requirement, you could check [**Distribute LOB apps to enterprises**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/distribute-lob-apps-to-enterprises) document.

> You have several options for distributing line of business (LOB) apps to your organization’s users using MSIX packages without making the apps broadly available to the public. You can use device management tools, configure an App Installer-based deployment, sideload the apps directly

And App Installer is suit for your scenario that double-clicking an .appinstaller file that installs the app package from a web server. For the detail steps you could refer to [Installing Windows 10 apps from a web page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/installing-windows10-apps-web) document.